# Installing jenkins on centos results in "No more mirrors to try."

Tags: jenkins, centos, vagrant

I'm running the vagrant box "puphpet/centos65-x64".

I followed the instructions here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Red+Hat+distributions

I install Java as stated on the bottom of that page, and then I follow the instructions at the top to install a stable version of Jenkins.

I continue to receive the following:

```
Error Downloading Packages:
jenkins-2.32.2-1.1.noarch: failure: jenkins-2.32.2-1.1.noarch.rpm from jenkins: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

I looked around online and people said to try `yum clean all` to ensure nothing is cached weird, but that doesn't seem to help me out.

Is there anything not stated in the docs that I should do?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the answer after a bit of lucky google-ing.
I will explain what I did so perhaps someone can chime in if they know exactly why this worked.

I was on a page that had a bunch of yum commands, and one was `yum check-updates`.  Since I'm dealing with a VM and I can do whatever with it, I decided to try to update everything and see what happens.

It failed due to a GPG key failure, but I noticed a package called yum.noarch.  "noarch" was part of the failed Jenkins package message, so I tried to manually update that single package:

```
yum update -y yum.noarch
```

I then re-ran:

```
yum install jenkins
```

Worked like a charm!